# What does "stdio" and "stdlib" stand for in C?

Tags: c++, c

And is there anywhere that explains all the shorthand library names?  I don't want documentation on what the libraries do, I just want to know what the titles are short for.  Are they abbreviations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to know how to find these for yourself. (I like Kerrek SB's list, but I can't blame you for wanting to know how to look these things up on your own.)

First things first: If you're on Debian or Ubuntu, I strongly recommend installing the `manpages-posix` and `manpages-posix-dev` packages in addition to the usual `manpages` package. These give you access to the [standards](http://www.unix.org/version3/) in addition to the [Linux man-pages project](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/).

The difference is immediately visible with:

```
man 2 close       # gives you the Linux documentation of the system call
man 3posix close  # gives you the POSIX definition of the function
```

You can also see the difference for functions that aren't likely to be system calls:

```
man 3 qsort       # Linux man-pages project describing the glibc function
man 3posix qsort  # POSIX standard definition of the function, should be useful
                    description for any POSIX-compliant system
```

I also recommend installing the `dict`, `dictd`, and `dict-jargon` or `dict-foldoc` (or both) packages:

```
$ dict stdin
2 definitions found

From The Free On-line Dictionary of Computing (26 July 2010) [foldoc]:

  standard input/output
  standard I/O
  stderr
  stdin
  stdio
  stdout

     <programming, operating system> The predefined input/output
     channels which every {Unix} process is initialised with.
     Standard input is by default from the terminal, and standard
     output and standard error are to the terminal.  Each of these
     channels (controlled via a {file descriptor} 0, 1, or 2 -
     stdin, stdout, stderr) can be redirected to a file, another
     device or a {pipe} connecting its process to another process.
     The process is normally unaware of such {I/O redirection},
     thus simplifying prototyping of combinations of commands.

     The {C} programming language library includes routines to
     perform basic operations on standard I/O.  Examples are
     "printf", allowing text to be sent to standard output, and
     "scanf", allowing the program to read from standard input.

     (1996-06-07)


From V.E.R.A. -- Virtual Entity of Relevant Acronyms (June 2006) [vera]:

  STDIN
         STandarD INput

$ dict stdlib
No definitions found for "stdlib"
$
```

(Hilarious, right? Doesn't have one of the ones you wanted. But still, they're wonderful tools.)

Comment: *`$ dict stdin`* -- just a typo? Maybe a programmer's joke to be off by one? ;-)

Answer (score 23):

OK, how about getting a list going then:

- "stdio": standard input/output
- "stdlib": standard library
- "printf": print formatted
- "fprintf": file print formatted ("print formatted to file")
- "sprintf": string print formatted ("print formatted to string")
- "vfprintf": variadic fprintf
- "fputc": file put char ("put char into file")
- "scanf": scan formatted
- "fread": file read ("read from file")
- "pthread": Posix thread
- "uint16_t": unsigned integral type, 16 bits wide
- "sigatomic_t": a type that can be accessed atomically in signal handlers
- "_t" in general: A suffix reserved for type names in the standard library.
- "float": floating point number
- "double": double-precision floating point number
- "char": character
- "bit": binary digit
- "fd": file descriptor
- "fcntl.h": file control  (Posix file descriptors)
- "ioctl.h": I/O control (also Posix)
- "stat": status of a file (also Posix)
- "lstat": status, possibly of a link itself
- "fstat": status of a file descriptor
- "sleep": interrupt normal activity in favour of no activity at all
- "usleep": version of the above that takes argument in microseconds (µs), with 'u' looking a bit like 'µ' whilst being basic ASCII
- "recv": receive
- "creat": create
- "str": string, in C this usually refers to null-terminated char arrays
- "strtok": tokenize string
- "pow": power
- "frexp": fractional part (significand) and exponent
- "abs": absolute value
- "malloc": memory allocate
- "calloc": allocate and clarify that the initial state is zero
- "wcsrtombs": wide character string to multibyte string, reentrant
- "wctomb": wide character to multibyte character(s)
- "iconv": ???
- "uconv": ICU version of "iconv"

Comment: good start.  now how did you know, for example, the "f" in "printf" stood for "format"?  you must have learned that somewhere...sure, a lot of them are obvious, but others not so much.  just seems like that'd be documented somewhere.  thanks though, i was wondering about a few on that list.

Comment: The `u` in `usleep` is not imperative. It's a mu (µ) for micro, because its argument is in microseconds.

Comment: @FrederickCraine: Because I/O can be either unformatted ("fread") or formatted ("fprintf"). Once you know that, you should be able to figure out what the "f" means. R.: Surely you must be joking. ;-)

Comment: @KerrekSB You're still referring to specific examples...I can't ask about every abbreviation I see, that's why I'm looking for somewhere I can find them on my own...don't give me a fish, TEACH me how to fish! :)

Comment: @FrederickCraine: I don't see why or how. None of this is magic. Once you know the underlying *concepts*, you should have no trouble inferring the meaning of any given symbol name. Consult a book or manual if you're unsure about what something *is*, and then you can surely figure out what its *name* means.

Comment: `lstat` is for _stat of symlink_, the `l` being for _link_.  As distinct from `stat` for _status of file (by name)_ and `fstat` for _status of file (by file descriptor)_.

Comment: There is no standard convention, @FrederickCraine; there are whatever conventions were chosen by the originator of whatever object you are asking about, often sometime in the '70s or '80s.  The best anyone can do is give you the derivation of specific names.

Comment: @KerrekSB so i'll just take that as "there is no one place to find them."  is that what you're saying?

Comment: And `calloc` doesn't _clarify_ (as in check) that the initial state is zero, it actively sets the bit patterns to zero. Mind you, the usleep one gave me a bit of a laugh but, unfortunately, no upvote while parts of the answer are wrong :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: not all of the descriptions are 100% serious, I'm afraid. I will gratefully take your tacit support for this answer as implied, though. :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo good example of when you could think it's something, and that it's not always something you can just figure out.  whether or not any one person sees how it would be useful, i do.

Comment: `frexp` is for the _fractional_ portion and the _exponential_ portion. And I think of `calloc` more as _clear the alloc_.

Comment: thanks guys.  i'll be able to check this list first now!  i'm suprised there's not some wiki about these already...

Comment: `iconv` is _input conversion_. :)

Comment: FWIW here's some speculation of where `calloc()`'s `c` came from: http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/acro/credits.htm#8

Comment: Note that `_t` is reserved by the *POSIX* standard, not the C++ standard.

Comment: Didn't the `int` in `uint16_t` mean integer instead of integral?

Answer (score 12):

Standard I/O (input-output) and Standard Library

Comment: And how did you know that?  I know google, but what if it wasn't there?  Is there naming documentation somewhere?

Comment: @Frederick: "std" is a VERY common abbrevation for "Standard".

Comment: that one has an explanation, but others (fcntl.h), don't.

Comment: @FrederickCraine: `<fcntl.h>` stands for "File Control".  It's right at the top of the man page for `fcntl` which reads `fcntl -- file control`.

Comment: @Dietrich, where can I find that?

Comment: Find the man pages?  If you are on a Unix-like system they are probably already installed and you just run `man fcntl`.  If that doesn't work, install the man pages.

Comment: aha that's it.  not all of them there, but that looks like what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

**stdio: Standard Input/Output**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/

"...using the C Standard Input and Output Library (cstdio, known as stdio.h in the C language)"

**stdlib: Standard Library**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/

"C Standard General Utilities Library
This header defines several general purpose functions..."